# I need help improving my validation code

Tags: c#, complexity-theory

When evaluated, the cyclomatic complexity of my code has a score of 10.  What is cyclomatic complexity and can anyone provide advice on reducing the complexity of the following code:

```
public override bool Validate(Control control, object value)
{
    if (value == null && !_IsAllowNull)
    {
        ErrorText = "Please provided valid number without a decimal point.";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (value.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
            ErrorText = "Decimal value is not allowed";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!value.IsNumber())
            {
                ErrorText = "Please provided valid number without a decimal point.";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value.ToInt() < _minValue || value.ToInt() > _maxValue)
                {
                    ErrorText = "Value should not be greater than " + _maxValue + " or less than " + _minValue;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The 'complexity' is based on the 'cyclomatic complexity', which represents the number of paths that your code can take. Usually caused by a bunch of nested `if`s, which is what you have currently. If you want to improve it, cut down on your `if`s.

Comment: And when you have working code and seek only advice on how to improve it, please use the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange instead. SO is for programming problems.

Comment: @Pierre ohh I see, I will try code review next time. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your validation checks are returning false, you don't need to `else` part so the code can just continue to the next check:

```
public override bool Validate(Control control, object value)
{
    if (value == null && !_IsAllowNull)
    {
        ErrorText = "Please provided valid number without a decimal point.";
        return false;
    }

    if (value.ToString().Contains("."))
    {
        ErrorText = "Decimal value is not allowed";
        return false;
    }

    if (!value.IsNumber())
    {
        ErrorText = "Please provided valid number without a decimal point.";         
        return false;
    }

    if (value.ToInt() < _minValue || value.ToInt() > _maxValue)
    {
        ErrorText = "Value should not be greater than " + _maxValue + " or less than " + _minValue;
        return false;
    }  

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest approach I can do now

Answer (score 1):

```
   public override bool Validate(Control control, object value)
    {
        if ((value == null && !_IsAllowNull) || !value.IsNumber())
        {
            ErrorText = "Please provided valid number without a decimal point.";
            return false;
        }

            if (value.ToString().Contains("."))
            {
                ErrorText = "Decimal value is not allowed";
                return false;
            }
            if (value.ToInt() < _minValue || value.ToInt() > _maxValue)
                    {
                        ErrorText = "Value should not be greater than " + _maxValue + " or less than " + _minValue;
                        return false;
                    }



        return true;
    }
```

Comment: this kind of i was trying to achieve lately but the problem with these is that the IsNumber() extension will not handled null values and will throw exceptions. so on the first condition, lets _IsAllowNull is true then the (value == null && !_IsAllowNull) is false then || condition will execute, and the !value.IsNumber() will throw an null exception

Answer (score 1):

With this your method complexcity score goes to 2

```
    public Validation()
    {
        _Validations = new List<Action<object>>
        {
            ValidateNull,
            ValidateDecimal,
            ValidateIsNumber,
            ValidateRange,
        };
    }

    public bool Validate(Control control, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            _Validations.ForEach(c => c(value));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorText = e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void ValidateNull(object value)
    {
        if (value == null && !_IsAllowNull)
            throw new Exception("Please provided valid number without a decimal point.");
    }

    private void ValidateRange(object value)
    {
        if (value.ToInt() < _minValue || value.ToInt() > _maxValue)
            throw new Exception("Value should not be greater than " + _maxValue + " or less than " + _minValue);
    }

    private static void ValidateIsNumber(object value)
    {
        if (!value.IsNumber())
            throw new Exception("Please provided valid number without a decimal point.");
    }

    private static void ValidateDecimal(object value)
    {
        if (value.ToString().Contains("."))
            throw new Exception("Decimal value is not allowed");
    }
```

Comment: I was wondering now if I will modify the whole class now. This could be good but, I think throwing an exception could be a performance hit.